# load parameter definitions from outside

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have some parameters in my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
properties(
    [parameters([
            [$class: 'ValidatingStringParameterDefinition', 
                defaultValue: '', 
                description: 'regex param', 
                failedValidationMessage: '', 
                name: 'VSTRING', 
                regex: '.+'
            ],
            [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', 
                defaultValue: 'some string', 
                description: 'string param',  
                name: 'STRING',
                trim: false
            ],
            [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',  
                name: 'CHOICE',
                choices: 'a\nb\nc', 
                description: 'coice param'
            ]
    ])]
)
```

Instead of defining those parameters inside the Jenkinsfile, I would like to load it from outside. For example, by parsing a JSON file, where I define my parameters.

I know how to create a JSON Object (using `shared libraries` to load the json-file and a groovy script to parse the content into json object), so I can do:

```
def jsonString = libraryResource 'params.json'
def myParams = jsonParse(jsonString)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
properties(
    [parameters([
        myParams
    ])]
)
```

Many different attempts failed. Actually, I have no idea how the syntax of my params.json has to look like - or if this works at all.

Hope you have some ideas how to load my parameter definitions from outside of the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it the following way:

Instead of creating a json file, I created a shared lib in may `vars` folder, with content:

```
// vars/myParamsLib.groovy
def call(){
    def params = []
    params.add([$class: 'ValidatingStringParameterDefinition', 
                defaultValue: '', 
                description: 'regex param', 
                failedValidationMessage: '', 
                name: 'VSTRING', 
                regex: '.+'
            ])
    // params.add(...)
    return params
}
```

And my Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([parameters(myParamsLib)])
```

Comment: This is good but doesn't seem to work for me in a Declarative pipeline. Is there an example of using that syntax?